# Postgres view role permissions

Tags: postgresql, permissions, role

I am trying to work out how database roles work.
Here is my user case...

```
create role user1 login password 'user1';

create schema authorization user1;

CREATE ROLE DEV_ROLE;

grant connect, temporary on database test to DEV_ROLE;
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA manager TO DEV_ROLE;
```

Now how do i view the all the grants assigned to 'DEV_ROLE'? This is possible in Oracle but trying to work out the same here.

Do appreciate your reply.
Ta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do that in PostgreSQL; you have to look at all ACLs on all objects.

Perhaps an extension like [pg_permissions](https://github.com/cybertec-postgresql/pg_permission) can be useful.

One other crude method I can think of:

```
BEGIN;
DROP ROLE dev_role;
ROLLBACK;
```

The `DROP ROLE` will give you a list of permissions it can find that are granted to the role.

Comment: `dev=# create extension pg_permissions;`
`ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/pgsql-12/share/extension/pg_permissions.control": No such file or directory`

Comment: Well, you need to install the software first. It is not a core extension.